# How to solve this problem in react native :component exception

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native

Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Check the render method of `Application`.

```
enter code here
import React, { Component } from 'react'; 
import { View, StatusBar, TouchableOpacity, Image } from 'react-native'; 
import Camera from 'react-native-camera'; 
import styles from './styles'; 
import PhotoCaptureIcon from '../assets/ic_photo_camera_36pt.png'; 


export default class Application extends Component { 
   constructor(props){
       super();
       this.camera=null;
   }

   takePicture= () =>{
       if(this.camera){
           this.camera.capture()
           .then((Data)=> console.log(data))
           .catch(err=> console.error(err));
       }
   }

   render(){
       return (
           <View style={styles.container}>
                <StatusBar animated hidden /> 
                <Camera 
                    ref={(cam) => { 
                        this.camera = cam; 
                    }} 
                    style={styles.preview} 
                /> 
            <View style={[styles.overlay, styles.bottomOverlay]}> 
                <TouchableOpacity style={styles.captureButton} onPress= {this.takePicture}>  

                    <Image source={PhotoCaptureIcon} /> 
                </TouchableOpacity> 
            </View> 
        </View>

       );
   }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You are basically referencing default export from react-native-camera. This won't work because it does not refer to the Camera component which is exported as RNCamera now. You can read more about this [here](https://react-native-community.github.io/react-native-camera/docs/expo_usage).

You need to replace this

`import Camera from 'react-native-camera';`

with this

`import { RNCamera as Camera } from 'react-native-camera'`.

This will correctly render the Camera component and the error should be fixed.
Good Luck

Comment: Good. If this helps please accept the answer or upvote it. Thanks